# Dynamic search with ElasticSearch and Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, elasticsearch

I'm creating an application with Laravel and ElasticSearch.

I have a page that acts as a search filter to find vehicles with a form with various filter types (brand, year, and optional).

The user can fill in all or just one of the fields.

```
$where = [];

if( $request->brand ){ 
    $where[] = " `brand` => '{$request->brand}'"; 
}
if( $request->year )
    { $where[] = " `cidade` => '{$request->year}'"; 
}
if( $request->item ){ 
    $where[] = " `bairro` => '{$request->item}'"; 
}
```

So I can get the fields that have been chosen by the user.

But I do not know how to do a dynamic query to query only the fields chosen by the user.

I can only search if the user fills in all the fields, like this:

```
    $this->elasticParams['body'] = [
        'query' => [
            'bool' => [
                'should' => [
                    ['match' => ['brand' => $request->brand]],
                    ['match' => ['year' => $request->year]],
                    ['match' => ['item' => $request->item]]
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ];
```

I would like to add only the fields that the user has filled out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know much about Elastic, but you should be able to conditionally add each field to the `'should'` part like this:

```
$should = [];

if ($request->brand) {
    $should[] = ['match' => ['brand' => $request->brand]];
}

if ($request->year) {
    $should[] = ['match' => ['year' => $request->year]];
}

if ($request->item) {
    $should[] = ['match' => ['item' => $request->item]];
}

// ...

$this->elasticParams['body'] = [
    'query' => [
        'bool' => [
            'should' => $should
        ]
    ]
];
```